# Fragment view not updating after reopening

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a couple text views in a nested fragment that updates as you touch different objects. When I first enter the fragment it works then when I replace the fragment and reopen it. All the views are click able but my text views are not updating. If I do

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_subtitle)).getText()
```

it returns the updated value as if it was working but the screen is not getting updated.
Its like i have an invisible copy of the text view some where

Unfortunately I can't post the source.

Comment: We can't really tell without code though

Comment: Facing same issue. Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work, since you haven't shown the code, but maybe you can override the `onPause()` method in the fragment to make the `MainActivity` class store the `TextView` information. Then, when you replace the next fragment with the fragment that's giving you the issue, you can set the `TextView`s to the data that was stored in the `MainActivity`. Does that make any sense?

EDIT: it might be the `onDestroy()` method if you don't invoke `addToBackStack()`

Comment: The issue is not the setting of the TextView. In debug I can see that the TextView value is being set the 2nd time. Its just not showing the updated value its like i have one textview on the screen then updating another not on the screen